# Spark : remove duplicated rows with different values using groupBy

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have a dataset `ds` like this:

```
ds.show():

id1 | id2 | id3 | value  |
1   | 1   | 2   | tom    |
1   | 1   | 2   | tim    |
1   | 3   | 2   | tom    |
1   | 3   | 2   | tom    |
2   | 1   | 2   | mary   |
```

I want to remove all duplicate rows (i.e. row 1 and row 2) for the given keys `(id1,id2,id3)`, but at the same time only keep one row for duplicated rows with same value (i.e. row 3 and row 4). The expected output is:

```
id1 | id2 | id3 | value  |
1   | 3   | 2   | tom    |
2   | 1   | 2   | mary   |
```

here I should remove row 1 and row 2 because we have 2 values for the key group. But we keep only one row for row 3 and row 4 because the value is the same (instead of removing these two rows)

I try to achieve this using:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, 1, 2, "tom"),
  (1, 1, 2, "tim"),
  (1, 3, 2, "tom"),
  (1, 3, 2, "tom"),
  (2, 1, 2, "mary")
).toDF("id1", "id2", "id3", "value")

val window = Window.partitionBy("id1", "id2", "id3")

df.distinct().withColumn("count", count("value").over(window))
  .filter($"count" < 2)
  .drop("count")
  .show(false)
```

This will return the correct result I want. However, I want to use `groupBy()` to achieve the same (instead of `Window`), but I don't know how to count when doing the `groupBy()` at the same time ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it with `groupBy`, `count` and `first` function

```
df.distinct()
  .groupBy("id1", "id2", "id3")
  .agg(count("value").as("count"), first("value").as("value"))
  .filter($"count" < 2 )
  .drop("count")
  .show(false)
```

Output:

```
+---+---+---+-----+
|id1|id2|id3|value|
+---+---+---+-----+
|1  |3  |2  |tom  |
|2  |1  |2  |mary |
+---+---+---+-----+
```